# How to make sections pages on Google Search?

Tags: seo, google-search

I don't know the name for this, but I want to see my website (https://larnia.co) on Google like Coursera:

[image: Google search Example]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are sitelinks and are [generated by a Google algorithm](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) that lets users rank them based on use and pogo-ing (returning to Google, to go elsewhere).

As I've learned from experience, your Nav links will be given priority. Make sure their anchor text is relevant and the container has either the word Nav in it or uses an HTML5 `<nav>` container. One of our sites was continually getting random highly ranked pages in the front page Sitelinks until we renamed the container.

If you don't have pages that are well linked or highly rated organically, sitelinks won't show up.